# Which one of the Gutter boys did it?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the quest Wont Get Fooled Again, you are tasked with solving a murder most foul.  I immediately noticed the quadruplets had different weapons and knew their equipment was going to be the key to identifying the killer.  The clues pertaining to their equipment were:

- The victim died of a **bullet** wound. (Wasn't the guy with the rocket launcher)
- One of the Gutter boys ran into Moxxi's looking for a safe haven.  **He had a shield**.

Since only one of the gutter boys had a shield, the choice seemed obvious.  When I accused him, One of the other suspects yelled "WRONG" and ran away.  I completed the quest and got the reward.  Did I miss something here?  Is this a scripted failure?  Would I have gotten a better reward if I had chosen correctly?

**Note:** Dr. Zed said he "healed one up as good as new", but I didn't see any evidence of this on any of them.

Comment: I did the same thing... I didn't realize you couldn't see the hp and shields by backing up, and couldn't see a Shield anywhere on the killer's body so assumed he didn't do it.

Comment: I never understood why the marshall would have seen the killer running away, when the guy uses a **sniper rifle**?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You were almost there. The clues are:

- Bullet Wound (Marshal Friedman tells you)
- Guy had a shield (Moxxi tells you)
- Guy now has full health (Dr. Zed healed him)

If you back up so the accuse option goes away, you'll see their health/shields instead.

Because it was a bullet wound we know it's not the guy with the rocket launcher (far right).
Because Moxxi said he had a shield we know it's not the guy on the far left (he doesn't have one).

This leaves the two guys in the middle, SMG guy and Sniper guy.

SMG guy is injured, not full health. Dr. Zed healed the guy so it wasn't him.

Only one left is sniper guy. He has a shield, full health, and a bullet weapon. Accuse sniper guy and he says "Yeah I did it, so what!?" and you've got him.

Comment: The logic for this has been bothering me every since I failed that quest a few days ago because I couldn't understand how to choose between SMG and Sniper guy. Thanks for solving that riddle for me and filling me in on what Dr. Zed's clue meant.

Comment: Ah, the health bars! Of course! I wasted my time looking for bullet holes or bandages on the models.

Comment: I have missed this one twice until looking it up.  I didn't see a shield on the sniper guy at all as far as a physical shield on him.  I didn't know about looking at the health bars :/

Comment: So why are we supposed to assume that the guy(s) that interacted with Moxxi and Zed was the killer? They could have been other brothers.

Answer (score 7):

[image: The Gutter boys]

In order to complete this quest, you're going to need to do some investigating. Go and question Moxxi, Friedman and Zed to get information on what they think happened, listen to what they have to say and then return to the scene to accuse the killer.

> "You would think that it’s the brother with the shield, but if you look at Justin’s hands, they form the type of weapon that was used; a sniper rifle from Barlo" - accuse him and complete the quest.

<sup>[Source](http://www.gamesradar.com/borderlands-2-side-missions-guide/?page=2)</sup>

Comment: And what about the quest reward?

Comment: @pixel: Incorrect, you do not necessarily get the sniper rifle for choosing correctly. I chose correctly, and received a pistol, Fine Law. 213 damage, 97.1 accuracy, 100% melee damage, 8 rounds per clip, 2.1 reload speed, 16.7 rate of fire (It's semi-auto, shoot as fast as you click)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to accuse one (by accident), at which point another started to crow about how he'd gotten away with it. I then selected him pretty quickly and the sheriff popped him (the guilty one) and rewarded me.